# Newbie having trouble getting GridView to work

Tags: asp.net

This is my first experience with using SqlDataSource and GridView, and I'm new to ASP.Net, so I'm struggling to make some of this stuff work.

I want to create a GridView from a SqlDataSource with a variable in the SQL Query coming from a form textbox. I can get the query and GridView to work without the form variable portion. Here is what I have:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CUBE %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CUBE.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT csono, citemno, nordqty, nseq, nprice, cdescript, nsalesamt FROM dbo.sostrs WHERE (LTRIM(csono) = @csono) ORDER BY nseq">
    <selectparameters>
        <asp:controlparameter name="csono" controlid="frmSONum" propertyname="Text"/>
    </selectparameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:TextBox ID="frmSONum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="citemno" HeaderText="citemno" 
            SortExpression="citemno" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cdescript" HeaderText="cdescript" 
            SortExpression="cdescript" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nordqty" HeaderText="nordqty" 
            SortExpression="nordqty" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nprice" HeaderText="nprice" 
            SortExpression="nprice" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nsalesamt" HeaderText="nsalesamt" 
            SortExpression="nsalesamt" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
</form>
```

When I run the form as-is I get this error:

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the variable '@csono'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed "@csono" to "?" in the SQL Query and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    /**/
    ,csono
    --,insert more select stuff
FROM
    yourTableName
WHERE
    csono = @csono
```

Generally, you'd add a line like this.

```
conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csono", yourValueHere);
```

This lets you avoid sql injection, which is what malicious people use to delete tables and fun stuff to your database.

More info here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396